# how to I override this validation for OmniAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, omniauth

I'm following the OmniAuth railscasts but I'm facing this issue.

The error message that I get when I try to login through Twitter is

```
Validation failed: Password digest can't be blank, Name can't be blank, Email can't be blank, Email is invalid, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters), Password confirmation can't be blank
```

I already have another authentication in place and I'm just trying to get OmniAuth to work alongside it.

I would like to get the username from Twitter and fill that in for the "Name". However, I would like to bypass the rest of the validation. So if a user signs up using Twitter, this user will have no email or password.

Here's my authentications controller

```
class AuthenticationsController < InheritedResources::Base

def index
    @authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
end

def create
  omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
  if authentication
     flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully"
     sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
  elsif current_user
   token = omniauth['credentials'].token
   secret = omniauth['credentials'].token
   current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'], :token => token, :secret => token_secret)
   flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful"
   redirect_to authentications_url
   else
    user = User.new
    user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
    if user.save!
    flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully"
     sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
   else
    session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
    redirect_to '/signup'
   end
end
end

def destroy
    @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
    @authentication.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed authentication"
    redirect_to authentications_url

end
end
```

schema.db

```
 create_table "authentications", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "secret"
    t.string   "token"
  end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
has_secure_password
  has_many :authentications
before_save { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

def apply_omniauth(omni)
 authentications.build(:provider => omni['provider'],
 :uid => omni['uid'],
 :token => omni['credentials'].token,
 :secret => omni['credentials'].secret)
 end

def twitter
unless @twitter_user
provider = self.authentications.find_by_provider('twitter')
@twitter_user = Twitter::Client.new(:oauth_token => provider.token, :oauth_token_secret => provider.secret) rescue nil
end
@twitter_user
end

def apply_twitter(omniauth)
if (extra = omniauth['extra']['user_hash'] rescue false)
# Example fetching extra data. Needs migration to User model:
# self.firstname = (extra['name'] rescue '')
end
end

def hash_from_omniauth(omniauth)
{
:provider => omniauth['provider'],
:uid => omniauth['uid'],
:token => omniauth['credentials']['token'],
:secret => omniauth['credentials']['secret']
}
end
end
```

I tried using `user.save(:validation => false)` in the authentication controller but it gave me a similar error.

Comment: You should have authentication method level not model level. Remove the validations for user model use authentication level validations. So different authentication can use different attributes.

Comment: is it possible to work around my existing code instead of applying authentication level validations?

Comment: @codeit I'm trying to do this myself with omniauth. When you say "method level" or "authentication level validations" what do you mean by that? Do I add the validations to a method in User.rb or do I create a new model Authentication.rb?